# Monthly check if an Employee has become a manager

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am new to PowerBi and was asked to create simple report showing who became a manager, on a monthly basis.
I know I could load two separate Excel source files (for current and previous month) and simply compare the values but I would like to research other approach.
I would like to load source from the folder, including report for every month and base the check on the "report date".
The calculation would have to consider current and previous month and give back result of whether the employee became a new manager.

What I would like to see as a result is possibly a calculated column or a measure showing the below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLxJj.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.